# Align the x-axis labels with the bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, count

I have a data set like that :

| Vente | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| Vente | 679 |
| Vente en l'état futur d'achèvement | 137 |

I used the following code :

```
g1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = libnatmut, y = counts, fill=libnatmut)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3, position=position_dodge2(preserve='single'))+
  labs(title = "Nature des mutations", x="Type de la vente",y="Nombre de ventes") +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts), vjust = -0.3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 17, hjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=14, angle=0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=14, angle=360),
        axis.title=element_text(size=22))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=24))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "#993333", 
                                 size = 1, linetype = "solid"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= rep_len(wes_palette("Zissou1"), 10))+
  theme(legend.position="none")

ggsave(g1, filename = "libnatmut.png", dpi = 300, height = 30, width = 30, units = "cm")
```

As we can see on the chart, the x-axis labels aren't aligned with my bars. I tried a lot of different things, but I can't manage to obtain a centered chart. [image]

It's probably pretty easy, but I only used R a long time ago so I'm not an expert at all with ggplot2.

Comment: You set `hjust = 1` in `axis.text.x` which right-justifies text. Remove that and the default will be centered. (Or set `hjust = 0.5` which is explicitly centered.)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that you have two calls to `axis.text.x` here. The second will override the first (as we can see by `angle=17` being ignored) so make sure you set `hjust` in the second one (and get rid of the first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the ggplot code a litte and used the data provided.

- Main action was to remove: `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 17, hjust = 1)) +`

```
library(wesanderson)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Vente, y = Nombre, fill=Vente)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3, position=position_dodge2(preserve='single'))+
  labs(title = "Nature des mutations", x="Type de la vente",y="Nombre de ventes") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Nombre), vjust = -0.3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=14, angle=0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333",size=14, angle=360),
        axis.title=element_text(size=22))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=24))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "#993333", 
                                 size = 1, linetype = "solid"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= rep_len(wes_palette("Zissou1"), 10))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Vente = c("Vente", "Vente en l'état futur d'achèvement"
), Nombre = c(679L, 137L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```